# Mypy error with valid Python 3.10 code involving pattern matching and type hints

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I have this code snippet in Python 3.10/3.11 and I'm trying to match on the type passed as argument, but mypy doesn't like it

```py
from typing import Type, TypeVar


def printTest(*args):
    ret = ltmItemFromIndex(*args)
    alt = ltmItemFromIndex_no_match(*args)
    test = 'Ok!' if (ret == alt) else 'Fail!'
    print(f"args: {args} | ret: {ret} | test: {test}", end="\n\n")


class LineItem:
    pass
class ObjectItem:
    pass
class RecipeItem:
    pass


LTM_ItemType = TypeVar("LTM_ItemType", LineItem, ObjectItem, RecipeItem)

def ltmItemFromIndex(item, itemType: Type[LTM_ItemType]) -> LTM_ItemType | str | None:
    match item:
        case itemType():
            print("case itemType():")
            return item
        case None:
            print("case None:")
            return None
        case _:
            print(error := f"TypeError: {type(item).__name__} instead of {itemType.__name__}!")
            return error
    
    
def ltmItemFromIndex_no_match(item, itemType: Type[LTM_ItemType]) -> LTM_ItemType | str | None:
    if isinstance(item, itemType):
        return item
    elif item is None:
        return None
    else:
        return f"TypeError: {type(item).__name__} instead of {itemType.__name__}!"


printTest(LineItem(), LineItem)
printTest(None, LineItem)
printTest(32, LineItem)
```

The code runs without any issues and can be tested here: https://onlinegdb.com/qTcB52ZH5
However, when I run it through mypy, it raises these errors:

```markdown
main.py: error: Expected type in class pattern; found "Type[__main__.LineItem]"  [misc]
main.py: error: Expected type in class pattern; found "Type[__main__.ObjectItem]"  [misc]
main.py: error: Expected type in class pattern; found "Type[__main__.RecipeItem]"  [misc]
```

https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=145441c5574c2bd1bc16a1835e311f69

I'm confused about why mypy is flagging these errors when the code seems to be correct.
Also, ltmItemFromIndex_no_match() runs fine and VSCode understands the types.
Can someone help me understand what's going on here?